# SVN: Write permissions to repo

Tags: svn, commit

when I'm trying to commit any file to my repo I'm getting following error:

```
svn: E200030: READONLY
```

I'm using Net Beans to commit files.

In my authz file, I've added:

```
[my_repo:/]
my_user = rw
```

I can do svn info, svn co, and so, but I'cant commit. Repo folder have rights 777 and all subfolders. But still no effect.

Comment: Did you restart svn server after you changed authz file?

Comment: @przno Yes, I just did, but with no effect.

Comment: Show config of used server

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the same error when you `svn import` a file to the repository? If you don't get the error then the broken working copy is the root cause. `svn checkout` a clean working copy and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what was the problem. The svn repo had no write rights to the folder that was placed. The second thing was that the repo was located on the remote server. Now I know that repo should be always placed locally, not on remote.